# Getting Error in populating table in server side datatable response data

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to get the data from datatable response. I am able to get the data, however, it seems because of the lenght, and [[prototype]] making the error for me.

I have here in my code

```js
let employees = ref([])

$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#datatable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
          complete: function (data) {
               console.log(data['responseJSON'].data)
               employees.value = data['responseJSON'].data
          },
          url: "/api/employee",
          type: "GET",
      },
    })
})
```

```html
<tr v-cloak v-for="employee in employees" :key="employee.ID">
   <td>
       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="employee.ID">
   </td>
   <td class="align-middle">{{ employee.EmployeeNo }}</td>
   <td class="align-middle">{{ employee.EmployeeName }}</td>
   <td class="align-middle">{{ employee.Company }}</td>
   <td class="align-middle">{{ employee.Branch }}</td>
   <td class="align-middle">{{ employee.DateHired }}</td>
   <td class="align-middle">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1">Details <em class="bi bi-arrow-right-square"></em></button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what I am getting when my page loaded.

[image]

The output after clicking Okay

[image]

And the console log

```html
0:
  Branch: "Tarlac"
  Company: "******"
  DateHired: "2021-08-25"
  EmployeeName: "************"
  EmployeeNo: "001"
  ID: 1
  [[Prototype]]: Object
1:
  Branch: "Aliaga"
  Company: "******"
  DateHired: "2022-08-01"
  EmployeeName: "TestName"
  EmployeeNo: "002"
  ID: 2
  [[Prototype]]: Object
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

My guess is I am getting the error because of the `length: 2` and `[[Prototype]]: Object`. Is it possible to remove it in response?

Hope you understand the point. Thank you!

Comment: why are you setting `employees.value = data['responseJSON'].data`? Maybe you want `employees = data['responseJSON'].data`

Comment: @aceraven777 same error. But without .value, no employee shown in the record.